# Magento 2 - Use secure url for static files field into database?

Tags: magento2, database, url

I'm using Magento 2, and I'm trying to find the field of "use secure URL for static files" (or similar label).

I can find `web/unsecure/base_url` into `mgxo_core_config_data` , but not that one, I need to delete it, as my website wouldn't load any resource on https for some reason.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command from your root install directory.

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --use-secure="0" --use-secure-admin="0"
```